# C# ZXing Error on Reader

Tags: c#, zxing

I developed this code and I need a help to correct. He does not correctly read the first number of bar code. What I need to change?

```
            //inicia o barcodeReader para ler a StringBuilder e seleciona o tipo de barcode, neste caso, qualquer tipo
            Bitmap image;`


            image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(recebe);

            LuminanceSource source;
            source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decodeWithState(bitmap);

            //faz um condicional para ler o que existe dentro da matriz Barcode
            foreach (string code in result)
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(nomePasta.ToString()))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(nomePasta.ToString());
                }
                else 
                { 

                }

                if (codigo == 0)
                {
                    codigo = Convert.ToInt32(0 + code);

                    File.Move(stringCaminho.ToString(), nomePasta.ToString() + code + ".bmp");
                }

                else if (codigo + 0 > Convert.ToInt32(0 + code))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Código de barras está errado! "+code);
                }

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(code);
                //esta dando erro para fazer o Move da segunda referencia


                }


                }
```

please help me , The first number is not correct
I'm taking one image from my PC , and he's have one barcode , the program read it , move and rename to number of the code .

Error:

> Error  1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ZXing.Result' because 'ZXing.Result' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    H:\Projetos\Qtrack_telas_old - Cópia\Qtrack_telas\frmScanner.cs 119 17  Qtrack_telas

Comment: Please correct the formatting and tell us what you have tried already.

Comment: Dont make us wade through all your code.  Post the *smallest* possible example that duplicates your problem, include error messages and sample input and expected output.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem , i believe to be on the ZXing.

Comment: I'm Editing ! Best now ?

Comment: What's the error message and in which line does it occur? [A propósito, já conhece o http://pt.stackoverflow.com ?]

Comment: The error is "Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ZXing.Result' because 'ZXing.Result' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' H:\Projetos\Qtrack_telas_old - Cópia\Qtrack_telas\frmScanner.cs 119 17 Qtrack_telas
"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you are trying to iterate over 'result' which is not something that is a collection (from my understanding).

The [docs for the api](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/Result.html) show that the 'Result' class has a method called 'getText' which seems to be how you get the string representation of the data that is in the result.

Without knowing what the loop is for I would suggest you refactor the code so that the loop is eliminated or put outside of this method.

Comment: Don't resolution. For example , I have one barcode , it's represent 3323, ok , but , the ZXing read  it with 2323 or 1323 or 5323 . Sometimes he reader correctly but no is ever

Comment: No image parser is perfect, are your source barcodes difficult to read?  Are they tightly spaced together or in a strange font?

Comment: Are code128, direct scanner scanner machine the resolution is good, I saved as .jpg, .bmp tb but does not give the spacing them're razuável, well separated.

Comment: Basically what you are saying is the code is working but the output is not what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, the output is wrong . The name of image not is barcode number

Comment: It sounds like its not an issue for Stack Overflow then, its sounds like the library you are using is not very good.